# IntelliJ IDEA: Multiline Commit Message

Tags: intellij-idea

How to write a multiline commit message in IntelliJ IDEA? I can do it in WebStorm and AppCode easily by pressing "Enter". In IntelliJ though, "Enter" performs the commit action (as if I clicked "Commit")

Comment: Which Language?

Comment: Throwing exception: which language - message language or coding language?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using? I've just tried this in 2017.2 and pressing ENTER works just fine when you enter a commit message - it takes you to the next line as you would expect.

Comment: I have issue doing it at the terminal in IntelliJ if you open a commit message with " and do not finish it , just the first line ios run

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done using the Terminal in IntelliJ. You can vote/give the thumbs up for adding this feature: [IDEA-278722 - Allow multi-line commit messages in Terminal window](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-278722)